# Ignore duplicate rows in COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query gives a count of how many rows there are in the exp_judging table with a value of 1 in the field pre, where there is also a matching column in exp_submissions with a member_group of 5

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_result
  FROM exp_judging AS jud
  LEFT JOIN exp_submissions AS sub ON jud.rel_id = sub.id 
  WHERE jud.pre = 1
        AND sub.member_group = 5
```

This works great. However, in the future there will be multiple rows with the same 'rel_id' in the 'exp_judging' table.

How can I ensure that only one of each row is counted?

I tried adding GROUP BY to the end, but it just shows 1 result then, instead of 4 before. (there are no duplicates yet)

```
GROUP BY jud.rel_id
```

EDIT:

Have tried the following, but still just shows 1:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT jud.rel_id) AS count_result
FROM exp_judging AS jud
LEFT JOIN exp_submissions AS sub ON jud.rel_id = sub.id 
WHERE jud.pre = 1
AND sub.member_group = $member_group
GROUP BY jud.rel_id
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT rel_id)` instead of `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud. Added an edit to my question, this still just shows 1, where it should be 4.

Comment: Okay, think I just clicked... no GROUP BY?

Comment: @ccdavies - Yes, no `GROUP BY` group by will give distinct results instead of count them all, remove it.

Comment: Thank you, this is great (stupidly I didn't know of the DISTINCT option).

Comment: @ccdavies - You're welcome any time, use `GROUP BY` if you want to get the count for each item for example if you have another column and you want to get the count or the sum of another column for each `rel_id` and never use `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` with the same column in the same time, it will give you the same what `SELECT DISTINCT ` does.

Answer (score 0):

try below query

```
 SELECT COUNT(jud.rel_id) AS count_result
 FROM exp_judging AS jud
 LEFT JOIN exp_submissions AS sub ON jud.rel_id = sub.id 
 WHERE jud.pre = 1
    AND sub.member_group = 5
group by jud.rel_id
```